# grails: how to test controller with multiple actions and multiple redirects?

Tags: testing, grails, redirect, controller, action

i am having the following problem:
i want to test the logout action of my controller. before that i am calling the login method of my controller which both redirect to the same page. now I am getting the following error message:

```
groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.
```

i do understand the problem, however all suggested solutions (calling the reset() method; calling GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest()) do not work.

i am doing integration testing and using the class ControllerUnitTestCase.

any suggestions?
thanks
dominik

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the answer(s):

1. I forgot to call the setUp from the super class:

   ```
   @Before
   void setUp() {
       super.setUp()
   ```
2. You cannot call reset() if you want to keep your session because it also clears your session. Call instead:

   ```
   redirectArgs.clear()
   ```

Cheers,
Dominik

Comment: Thanks! BTW what do setup do to allow this?