# Unit test controller by calling multiple actions

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a very similar problem to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862622/grails-how-to-test-controller-with-multiple-actions-and-multiple-redirects). (The main difference being that i am using Grails 2.1).

Basically i want to write a unit test which does sth like:

```
// set params so i can create an obj.
def results = controller.save()

// validate results or model/view
results = controller.edit(id, version)
```

However, this doesn't work, because the first method action (save) has triggered a redirect and the second one would too, which leads to a CannotRedirectException.
With the message:

```
Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.
```

The proposed solution for this (found in various places) is:

```
redirectArgs.clear()
```

However, this doesn't work, because since Grails 2, redirectArgs doesn't exist, there is only

```
response.redirectUr
```

which can only be read, not written to.

I have also already tried these things (in various combinations):

```
response.reset()
clearGrailsWebRequest()
bindGrailsWebRequest()
cleanupGrailsWeb()
controller.redirect([:])
controller.redirect(null)
controller = new OfferObjectController()
controller = mockController(OfferObjectController)
```

All without any luck.

I have totally run out of ideas what else could work/help.
Any suggestion is appreciated!

==== EDIT ====

i forgot to clarify that

```
response.reset()
```

kind of works, it lets me call another action, however it seems to undo/rollback the changes done by the previous action, which is exactly what i want to avoid (if i wanted that, i would put the call into its own test[method]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

```
response.reset()
```

I don't know why you're receiving that exception. By the way, you should create one task one test.

I guess you can try this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
.....

// set params so i can create an obj.
def results = controller.save()

def lastRequest = GrailsWebRequest.lookup().currentRequest
lastRequest.removeAttribute("org.codehaus.groovy.grails.REDIRECT_ISSUED")

// validate results or model/view
results = controller.edit(id, version)
```

Comment: yes, you are basically right, i didn't explain that in my question, edited it to clarify. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, I edited my answer. I don't test that, only guessing. Please tell me if it work.

Comment: Damn, i was almost certain that that would work (judging from the code), however it yielded the same result as the response.reset(), which means it got the action from the controller.save() (adding an object instance) undone, which is at least an unexpected behaviour.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I think that if you remove REDIRECT_ISSUED attribute then request is canceled, thus your object session is not flushed, maybe if you flush your session in your first method then you can use response.reset() I don't know, only lucubration. Can you show me your controller.save() method?

Comment: the save() method is basically just the usual
    `def offerObjectInstance = new OfferObject(params)
    if (!offerObjectInstance.save(flush: true)) {`
followed by some error handling. I tried to flush the session, but somehow i can't get to it:
    `context.getBean('sessionFactory')`
fails, because it says that this bean doesn't exist.
I have pretty much given up on testing it this way now. With grails it simply seems to be the way "Convention or GTFO" (Do it the Grails way or don't do it). I better get used to that fast ^^
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: oh my god, i feel so incredibly stupid right now... YES, `response.reset()` works perfectly! My tests failed because of a totally different reason and i was too blind to see (expected groovy to convert Strings to Longs, which resulted in the ascii value). I really feel stupid now for blaming Grails, i really want to bang my head against the wall -_- Sorry for the time this cost you & thanks!